# nginx redirect to other application if 404

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I am running two Flask applications on my server. The first one has an nginx config in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/alpha-project`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3033;
    }
}
```

Therefore, whenever I visit `mywebsite.com`, I can use this application (named `alpha-project`).

Now I have another flask applicaton called `beta-project` with the config file `/etc/nginx/sites-available/beta-project`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location /beta {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3034;
    }
}
```

I want to use my `beta-project` whenver I visit `mywebsite.com/beta`.
However when I visited `mywebsite.com/beta`, the server always returned 404. It seemed like I was still using the `alpha` application.

How can I make nginx redirect to my `beta` application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that both servers don't have a virtual name. You need to either combine them into one config

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3033;
    }

    location /beta {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3034;
    }
}
```

Or you need to use two separate virtual server names

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name servera;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3033;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name serverb;
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:3033;
    }
}
```

Then you can reach main server at `http://servera/` and other one at `http://serverb/beta`. Both `servera` and `serverb` names should resolve to the IP using `/etc/hosts` or the DNS names